# How to use user-event library in conjunction with Jest's fake timers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, settimeout, user-event

I'm writing Jest tests for a React component, and using the `@testing-library/user-event` library to simulate user interaction. This works great, except in tests that use Jest's fake timers.

Here's a sample test:

```js
it(`fires onClick prop function when the button is clicked`, async () => {
  // jest.useFakeTimers()

  let propFn = jest.fn()

  let app = RTL.render(
    <SampleComp onClick={propFn} />
  )

  await userEvent.click(app.queryByText('Test button')!)

  expect(propFn).toHaveBeenCalled()

  // jest.useRealTimers()
})
```

And here's the component:

```js
function SampleComp({ onClick }) {
  // a simple bridge for debugging
  function _onClick(e) {
    console.log(`_onClick invoked`)
    return onClick(e)
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={_onClick}>
      Test button
    </button>
  )
}
```

Without fake timers, the test runs in a fraction of a second and passes. With the fake timers, the test times out and then fails:

```
  ● fires onClick prop function when the button is clicked

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

It also fails to emit the debug line, so evidently the click event is never fired.

I've done a whole bunch of debugging, and have determined that the root cause is that the user-event library relies on a `setTimeout` internally to create a brief delay between events.

Yes, "events" *plural* -- recall that the value-proposition of the user-event library is:

> `fireEvent` dispatches DOM events, whereas `user-event` simulates full *interactions*, which may fire multiple events and do additional checks along the way.
> -- [user-event docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro/#differences-from-fireevent)

In this case, user-event creates two events for me:

1. a mouse movement<sup>1</sup>
2. the actual click

<sup><sup>1</sup>Although user-event's internal event object for the first event has only a `target` and no `type`, it makes sense to me that the first event would be either mouse-move or mouse-over on the button. Regardless: I've verified that the list of actions user-event creates internally does have 2 items, and the second one is clearly marked as "[MouseLeft]".</sup>

The delay is inserted between events by user-event's [`pointerAction` function](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/main/src/pointer/index.ts#L58). In my case, user-event stalls out during the delay between events 1 and 2.

The timeout is created in [user-event's `wait` module](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/main/src/utils/misc/wait.ts#L9):

```js
new Promise<void>(resolve => globalThis.setTimeout(() => resolve(), delay))
```

I've verified that this is the problem by monkeypatching that line inside my node_modules to simply resolve immediately without a timer, like so:

```js
new Promise<void>(resolve => resolve())
```

Unfortunately, my application code has some important timers, and it won't do to make the test suite wait for them in real time. And even if I could, I suspect folks who find this question later might not have that freedom.

It does not work to run Jest's fake timers to permit user-event to proceed, like so:

```js
it(`fires onClick prop function when the button is clicked`, async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers()

  let propFn = jest.fn()

  let app = RTL.render(
    <SampleComp onClick={propFn} />
  )

  let userAction = userEvent.click(app.queryByText('Test button')!)

  jest.runOnlyPendingTimers() // no good
  jest.runAllTimers() // also no good

  await userAction

  expect(propFn).toHaveBeenCalled()

  jest.useRealTimers()
})
```

So, how is one supposed to use Jest's fake timers in conjunction with the user-event library?

---

In this case, versions do seem to matter: this test worked great with earlier versions of React, Jest, and user-event. Here are the versions I'm using now (where this breaks), as well as the versions I was using (where this works):

| Library | Current (breaks) | Previous (worked) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jest | [v27.5.1](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/v27.5.1) | [v26.6.3](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/v26.6.3) |
| react | [v18.1.0](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/v18.1.0) | [v16.13.1](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/v16.13.1) |
| @testing-library/user-event | [v14.3.0](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/tree/v14.3.0) | [v12.8.3](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/tree/v12.8.3) |

I should note that it's not possible to change the package versions being used. I need a solution that works with the specific versions listed in the "Current" column.

Note: I think this problem is not specific to React, and folks using Vue or Svelte or anything else would have the same problem as long as they're using Jest's fake timers + user-event (which are both framework agnostic). So, I'm not tagging it as React.

Comment: Have you tried actually running the fake timers in your tests?

Comment: It turns out that running the fake timers doesn't help. I tried `runOnlyPendingTimers` and `runAllTimers`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the [delay](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/options#delay) using the `user-event` setup function:

```js
const user = userEvent.setup({ delay: null })
```

Make sure to then use the instance returned by `setup()`:

```js
await user.click(app.queryByText('Test button')!)
```

Comment: This is what I actually did, and it worked in every single case.

Answer (score 6):

Did you try this:

```js
const ue = userEvent.setup({ advanceTimers: jest.advanceTimersByTime });
```

In my case it didn't work if it was not set up. More here [Mocking setTimeout with Jest](https://marek-rozmus.medium.com/mocking-settimeout-with-jest-3fd6b8fa6307)

Comment: This looks promising, but I haven't actually tried it yet.

Comment: And to get this working, you must call `useFakeTimer` before `setup`.